# Android ARM Assembly prinft

Tags: android, assembly, arm

```
... starts here                 

stmfd   sp!, {r0, r1, r2, r3, ip, lr}
bl      printf
ldmfd   sp!, {r0, r1, r2, r3, ip, lr}

... should comback here
```

I added this assembly code in Dalvik VM and it seems the code I added does not blow up the program. But where do I see the printf? I check DDMS and console but none of them printing out something.

Comment: Like any other embedded device you likely have to redirect standard output.

Comment: Could you explain how to do this?

Comment: Sorry I have no idea on Android native. There should be some docs in the NDK however. Have you tried running you program from the shell?

Answer (score 2):

have you tried call putchar() to print something on the console?